# Black screen with forced anti aliasing

Tags: opengl, nvidia, antialiasing, amd-processor

NVIDIA/AMD driver utilities allows user to force anti aliasing for specific game and sometimes it's forced by default.

My project is a simple 2D OpenGL-based game and there is a problem: when anti aliasing is forced, the game window appears completely black. It works properly if you switch anti aliasing settings to "controlled by application".

Is there a way to prevent drivers from forcing this setting?
I can imagine some kind of manifest/profile which comes along with application binary and the driver reads default settings but googling yields nothing.

Comment: I think the current settings do a rather good just of making sure the user does not force anti-aliasing...

Comment: The problem is that some users have driver setup which forces anti-aliasing by default for all games and my game shows black screen unless the user manually selects "application controlled anti aliasing".

Comment: Hmm that is annoying. Your best bet would probably be to figure out how to add support for anti-aliasing. There wouldn't be much point in the flag if programs could just override it. Though really if users are changing settings that even the driver says might cause problems, it's their own fault.

Comment: On the positive side, it is probably a simple error that is causing MSAA to yield a black screen.